# Adjust the comma using only if-else

Tags: php

```
<?php
$one = "A";
$two = "f";
$three = "";
$four = "d";
$output = "";
$output = $one.",".$two.",".$three.",".$four;
if ($four == "") {
    echo $output;
}
elseif ($three == "") {
    echo $output;
}
elseif ($two == "") {
    echo $output;
}
elseif ($one == "") {
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

Hi, the output of the above program gives me as A,f,,d now i don't want the empty space between two values if i omit any one of them,can any one please tell me how to do that.

Please note that i need to use only if-else statements and no loops can be used.

Thank you.

Comment: I think it for your evaluation, try more to do it yourself rather asking here, as it is your class assignment. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot...and i did try a lot, my tutor just confused me, i had to ask here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use arrays? You could do something like

```
$output = implode(',', array_filter(array($one, $two, $three, $four)));
```

Comment: Thanx this helped me, it was an assignment for me to just use if-else, but i guess i could use arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $one = "A";
    $two = "f";
    $three = "";
    $four = "d";
    $output = "";

    if($output && $one){
        $output .= ",".$one;
    }else{
        $output .= $one;
    }

    if($output && $two){
        $output .= ",".$two;
    }else{
        $output .= $two;
    }

    if($output && $three){
        $output .= ",".$three;
    }else{
        $output .= $three;
    }

    if($output && $four){
        $output .= ",".$four;
    }else{
        $output .= $four;
    }
    echo $output;
?>
```

check here : https://eval.in/540856

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i want!